# There are crontab may be a malware

Tags: 14.04, cron

I need a help for explain and resolve about log my server, syslog always record the log

```
CRON[8944]: (ftpuser) CMD (/home/ftpuser/.profiles/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

although I have been delete the user `ftpuser` and home directory user.

```
Oct 14 09:32:01 sarirotidbdr CRON[8944]: (ftpuser) CMD (/home/ftpuser/.profiles/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 14 09:32:04 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:32:04 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:32:04 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:32:04 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:32:23 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:32:23 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:32:49 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:32:49 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:32:49 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:32:49 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:33:01 sarirotidbdr CRON[11192]: (ftpuser) CMD (/home/ftpuser/.profiles/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 14 09:33:32 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:33:32 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:33:44 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:33:44 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:33:44 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:33:44 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:34:01 sarirotidbdr CRON[11228]: (ftpuser) CMD (/home/ftpuser/.profiles/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 14 09:34:20 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:34:20 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:34:48 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:34:48 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:34:48 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Connection terminated abnormally
Oct 14 09:34:48 sarirotidbdr SQLAnywhere(nicsecondaryserver): Disconnected TCPIP client's AppInfo: HOST=sarirotiappdr
Oct 14 09:35:01 sarirotidbdr CRON[11258]: (ftpuser) CMD (/home/ftpuser/.profiles/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have some cron jobs doing this command. Have a look at `crontab -l -u root` and files under `/var/spool/cron/`.

If you believe your machine was compromised the only sane solution would be to reinstall everything from scratch and from known good and non infected backups.